# How to select count from Table A with conditions from Table B

Tags: postgresql

First, apologies if the title doesn't make much sense, I can't properly describe it in the title, my apologies.

I have 4 tables: Jobs, Tasks, Employees, and Status. Each Job has tasks (plural) and each task has a set of employees that will execute the task.

What I want to output is a list of Employees and the number of jobs that they have completed, with the "status" to check if the Job is completed found in the Jobs table.

The following is my expected outcome:

```
Employee Name | Jobs Completed
Bob           | 3
Andy          | 2
Carl          | 1
```

I have attached a db-fiddle to help illustrate my question:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/izPsVVxPZ8e9ZMPwbL9her/8

I've been reading about outer joins, but can't make it work.
Hope you can help me figure out how to execute this, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the count of finished jobs, you need a group by:

```
select t.employee_id, count(*) as num_done
from tasks t
  join jobs j on t.job_id = j.id
  join status s on s.id = j.status_id 
where s.name = 'Done'
group by t.employee_id
```

This can be joined to the employees table to get the employee's name

```
select e.id, e.name, x.num_done
from employees e
  join (
    select t.employee_id, count(*) as num_done
    from tasks t
      join jobs j on t.job_id = j.id
      join status s on s.id = j.status_id 
    where s.name = 'Done'
    group by t.employee_id
  ) x on x.employee_id = e.id
order by x.num_done desc;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ead3424aba4f5905e0f5119e971f51e6&hide=1)

(Note that Andy also has three jobs that are "Done", not 2 as in your expected output)